# What is the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{kx}$?

Tags: summation

My Precalc teacher gave me this as a question and I simply cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: It's a geometric series with $r = e^x$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I tried plugging in 1, 2, 3, and 4 then I plugged in n-1 and tried to find something that made a rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call this sum $S_n(x)$, i.e.
$$
S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{kx}.
$$
Clearly $S_n(0)=n$. For $x\ne 0$, if you multiply $S_n(x)$ by $e^x$, you get:
\begin{eqnarray}
e^xS_n(x)&=&e^x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{kx}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{(k+1)x}=e^x+e^{2x}+\ldots+e^{(n-1)x}+e^{nx}\\
&=&-\color{blue}{1}+\underbrace{[\color{blue}{1}+e^x+e^{2x}+\ldots+e^{(n-1)x}]}_{S_n(x)}+e^{nx}\\
&=&-1+S_n(x)+e^{nx}.
\end{eqnarray}
Solving
$$
e^xS_n(x)=-1+S_n(x)+e^{nx}
$$
for $S_n(x)$ you get:
$$
S_n(x)=\frac{1-e^{nx}}{1-e^x}.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{kx}=\begin{cases}
n &\mbox{ for } x=0\\
\frac{1-e^{nx}}{1-e^x} &\mbox{ for } x\ne 0
\end{cases}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity
$$
1+a+a^2+\dotsb+a^{n-1}=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}
$$
Because if $S=1+a+a^2+\dotsb+a^{n-1}$ then
$$
aS=a+a^2+\dotsb+a^{n}=S+a^n-1
$$

Comment: What could i do if I forget this identity during a test?

Comment: Take a look at new edit.

Comment: *What could i do if I forget this identity during a test?*  Figuring it out today by yourself (instead of having us do it for you) would have helped you remember it...

Comment: Well to figure it out myself, I need to understand how one derives it to actually apply it

Comment: @user237616 If you forget it during a test and cannot remember how to derive it, then all you can do is write that you understand this is a geometric series, that $r = e^x$, and that there is a formula to find the sum of such a series but you cannot remember it.  A good teacher should give some partial credit for that (a bad teacher won't).